# How to write table on Juliabox?

Tags: julia, jupyter

I define a DataFrame named data and want to write it into .csv file. I used `writetable("result_data.csv", data)`  but it doesn't work.
[This is the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unv08.png)

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEftr.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write a data frame to a disk you should use the CSV.jl package like this (also make sure that you have write right to the directory you want to save the file on Juliabox):

```
using CSV
CSV.write("result_data.csv", data)
```

If this fails then please report back in the comment I will investigate it further.